# Extract person from video

Tags: video, video-editor, editing, software, effects

Is there a way to extract a person from a video without having a blue- (or green-)screen?

Any software which can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a frame where the person does not exist, you can use a tool called a [difference matte](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/keying-effects.html). (You'll need to scroll down to the section titled "Difference Matte Effect" for a description.) It will find a difference between the frame without the person, and the frames with a person and remove areas that are the same, leaving only the difference (in this case the person). As linked, After Effects has such a tool. Many other video editors have it as well.

Comment: Thanks, let me just link the following thread, which also mentiones other software for achieving this: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4306/difference-matte-keying-software

Answer (score 5):

Final Cut Pro X has a plugin called [Pro Removal](http://store.pixelfilmstudios.com/product/proremoval/) that can remove moving things from the scene on fixed camera shots.

Also [there is a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAWv1XFrrTQ) for After Effects that shows how remove objects from scene using the tracker.

Also you can clean frame by frame using Photoshop or similar if you have a good amount of time to spend or a crew to help you in the task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfornutaley I do not have both programs, so may I ask is there any freeware or open-source program out there that can accomplish this task... would be glad if you can add them to the list!

Comment: You could use the compositing tools in Blender to do this. Blender is free.